# MASM32 qeditor linker error LNK1181

Tags: linker-errors, masm, masm32

I have masm32 installed for quite a while now, and it always worked fine when I used the qeditor. An hour ago, however, I started getting a linker error:

> Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 6.14.8444 Copyright (C)
>   Microsoft Corp 1981-1997.  All rights reserved.
>
> Assembling: C:\Documents and Settings\xxx\Bureaublad\masm\sdfsdf.asm
>
> ***** ASCII build
>
> ---
>
> Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 5.12.8078 Copyright (C)
>   Microsoft Corp 1992-1998. All rights reserved.
>
> LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file "C:\Documents and
>   Settings\xx x\Bureaublad\masm\sdfsdf.obj"
>   _ Link error

The object file sdfsdf.obj seems to be generated in C:\masm32, for some reason. I googled and found [this forum post](http://www.masmforum.com/board/index.php?topic=11457.0) on the masm32 forum, but it doesn't help me any further.

I'm sure the source I'm trying to assemble is correct MASM assembly, the same source assembled fine before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click `File`, `Set Current Directory` (or press Ctrl+F12). Then select the directory where your project is located. After that you should be able to assemble and link the project successfully.